# MASM x86 Assembly Iterative Addition to Evaluate Factorials

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, factorial

I've got a problem here.
I need to create a single loop that takes a pre-set number (saved in ebx) and computes its factorial, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do it. My limiting factor is that you cannot use any multiplication commands.
Here is the basic format of what the problem is:

```
;preceding code
mov eax, 0 ;n! will be stored in eax
ecx = ebx ;ebx = n

factorial: ;computes n! 
  ;some algorithm I have not figured out
  ;
  ;
loop factorial

;eax = n!
```

Any ideas on what this algorithm might be?

UPDATE: I found the algorithm, I had to write it in C because I am much more fluent in that than x86 assembly.

```
int x = z; //z is the number we want z! from
int y = 0;
int n = x;
int i, j;

for(i = x - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  for(j = n; j > 0; j--)
    y += i;
  n = y;
  y = 0;
}
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Currently attempting to translate into Assembly.

HERE is the final translation/answer for all future coders out there. Question solved.

```
;FACTORIAL WITHOUT MULTIPLICATION
mov ecx, ebx   
mov edx, 0
mov eax, ebx
dec ecx
jz next
factorial:
  mov edi, ecx
  mov ecx, eax
  factorial2:
    add edx, edi       
  loop factorial2
  mov ecx, edi
  mov eax, edx
  mov edx, 0
loop factorial
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the largest factorial that can be stored in a 32 bit integer is 12! using a loop is not required. It is much easier and faster to just store the factorials in table and look them up.

A code without range checking could be somewhat like this:

```
  ; assumes n is stored in EBX

  lea edi, [FactorialTable]
  mov eax, [edi + ebx*4]
  ret                          ; return from subroutine

FactorialTable:
  dd 1  ; factorial of 0 is 1
  dd 1
  dd 2
  dd 6
  dd 24
  dd 120
  dd 720
  dd 5040
  dd 40320
  dd 362880
  dd 3628800
  dd 39916800
  dd 479001600
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! But I actually need to calculate it for an assignment, rather than for real-world applications (of course a table would be better!) Also, I am only working with integers 1-10, so 32-bit is fine for 10!.